# Key Computation using openSSL APIs in C

Tags: openssl

Please suggest me how to implement the following equations using openssl in C.

```
Out = A^x mod y;
```

Where Exponent `x` is random and `y` is Diffie-Hellman prime modulus.

`A` = SHA256 (Buffer1 concatenate with Buffer 2).

Comment: If you are trying to perform the first part of Diffie-Hellman (generating the private key), there's a function `DH_generate_key()`. But using a random (uncontrolled) value for the generator (SHA256) may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear, so I'll just point out the parts you might be interested.

### SHA256 digest

For making a SHA256 digest, look at EVP_Digest [page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html). Also take a look at cyprto/sha1test.c for usage. Replace `EVP_sha1()` with `EVP_sha256()` in this line

```
EVP_Digest(*P,strlen((char *)*P),md,NULL,EVP_sha1(), NULL);
```

### BIGNUMs

For x and y, they are stored as BIGNUMs in OpenSSL. [Here](http://edc.tversu.ru/elib/inf/0088/0596003943_secureprgckbk-chp-7-sect-4.html) is a clear and simple guide to BIGNUMs. Also look at crypto/bn/bntest.c for usage examples.

### SHA256 digest to BIGNUM

Now you need to convert message digest A to a BIGNUM, look [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html) and select an appropriate function that fits your needs. `BN_bin2bn()` might be what you're looking for. If the resulting BIGNUM bn_A is larger than modulus `y`, this function will do `bn_A = bn_A mod y` for you:

```
int BN_mod(BIGNUM *rem, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx);
```

, or if you expect both `bn_A` and `y` to be non-negative,

```
int BN_nnmod(BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx);
```

### Random BIGNUM x

Suppose you already assigned modulus `y` and you want to come up with a random number x such that `0=<x<y`, make use of this function

```
int BN_rand_range(BIGNUM *rnd, BIGNUM *range);
```

See [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_rand.html) for BIGNUM rand functions information.

### Modular Multiplication of BIGNUMs

Finally it's time to do the modulus multiplication, use this function (described [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_add.html)):

```
int BN_mod_mul(BIGNUM *r, BIGNUM *a, BIGNUM *b, const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx);
```

For usage of this function, you can refer to function `test_mod_mul` in crypto/bn/bntest.c

And that should do it.